# What is the difference between a chest and a trunk?

Tags: meaning, differences

Is a "trunk" more likely to have a "flat top" and a "chest" more likely to have a "rounded top"?

Comment: The words overlap somewhat, but although it's true *chest* is more associated with *rounded top*, a bigger difference is probably that *trunks* are more associated with *luggage*, and being *moved, taken outside the house, taken on holiday,* etc.

Comment: Might also be a BrE/AmE, or other regional difference.

Comment: Interestingly, both 'chest' and 'trunk' have anatomical meanings.

Answer (score 1):

A trunk is a piece of luggage.  It is most often rectangular with a large latch on the top opening.  It can be made out of almost any material but the material is usually light so that it can be transported easier.  Also it will have protection pieces (strapping) that will add a little distance from main shell and potential harm.

A chest is shaped much like a trunk (almost always without the strapping).  They can be made of heavier material, since they are made to keep things in (your home or secret treasure spot).  Chests can have different compartments and their insides are usually a little fancier.  Most trunks just have a huge opening where a lot of chests might have several compartments.  Also although a lot of chests may have a latch top - which is perfect for traveling - their opening mechanism for the top is quite a bit more variable. On the topic of rounded top, I would say that most of the time it would be a chest because it would be hard to stack your trunk when traveling with a round top.  But most chests do not have round tops so don't less this limit your use of the word.

The two words can be synonyms of one another but there are small details that would warrant one's use of the other.  If it were for traveling I would almost always use trunk.  If it didn't have a latch top or if it had fancy compartments I would almost always use chest.

Comment: +1.  A trunk is meant for traveling, and a chest generally stays put.

Answer (score 0):

"Chest" isn't a synonym for trunks which are often square. When most people imagine a chest they imagine a rounded top box from the book "Treasure Island". You could call a chest a trunk however, since it is a type of trunk.